# Persistence error locally in Firebase - React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I'm configuring Firebase persistence in my firebase.js file to save locally so I can export my variable throughout my app but I get the following error: **FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/already-initialized)., js engine: hermes**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "ACHT5u4sf4",
  authDomain: "eacom",
  projectId: "ef",
  storageBucket: "easom",
  messagingSenderId: "93",
  appId: "1:9600e56",
};

export const firebaseapp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(firebaseapp);
export const auth = initializeAuth(firebaseapp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error keeps coming because you probably tried to use the 'auth' you created using the initializeAuth. You don't need to change anything in the code, you only need to add the following:

1. import {getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth"
2. make an instance of getAuth: --> const authy = getAuth();
3. useEffect(() => {
   signInWithEmailAndPassword(authy, "email", "password");
   }, [])
4. The useEffect is optional, but I set it to mount on the app startup

Answer (score 0):

If the error persists try this in your app.js file:

```
if(initializeApp(firebaseConfig) !== null){
   const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
        persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
    })
}


Then in your aunthentication.js file try the following:
 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
 const authy = getAuth(app);
 signInWithEmailAndPassword(authy, email, password);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The reason is you probably added

```
export const auth = initializeAuth(firebaseapp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage),
});
```

after running the project once, which is why the firebaseApp (as well as auth) was already initialized and hence you were getting the error.

You can simply recompile/restart the server and won't see any issues.